# The probability of sample covariance matrix to be positive definite is 1.

Tags: probability-distributions

In the book "An introduction to multivariate statistical analysis" by T.W. Anderson, I note that the probability of $A=\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\bar{x})(x_i-\bar{x})^T$ with $\bar{x}=\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i/N$ to be positive definite is $1$.

How to prove $$Pr(|A|=0)=0,$$
when $N>p$, $p$ is the dimension of random vector $x$. Can anyone give some outlines to me?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the $x_i$ are iid and drawn from a continuous nondegenerate distribution on $\mathbb{R}^p$.  To make things easier, let's replace each $x_i$ with $y_i = x_i - \overline{x}$.  Then
$$ A = \sum_{i=1}^N y_i y_i^T. $$
In order for $A$ to be positive definite, it suffices to show that $v^T A v > 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^p$.  This is satisfied if 
$$ v^T y_i y_i^T v  = (v \cdot y_i)^2 > 0$$
for every $i$.  By assuming $N > p$, this occurs with probability one (why?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I also get the first part. But the second part that how the probablility equals 1 by assuming $N>p$ also puzzled me.

Comment: We could have made the weaker statement that $(v \cdot y_i)^2 > 0$ for *some* $i$ (we just need the sum $v^T A v = \sum (v\cdot y_i)^2$ to be positive).  Then if some vector $v$ fails this, it must be perpendicular to all the $y_i$.  That means all $N$ of the $y_i$ must lie in a $(p-1)$-dimensional subspace.  Of course $\{y_1, \dots, y_{p-1} \}$ will lie in such a subspace, but what is the probability that $y_p$ lies in the same space?  Here is where we invoke the nondegeneracy of the distribution.

Comment: Thanks alot, I think I have understand your idea!